# Show $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$ if $p\not=q$ "explicitly", without theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

So, this could be wrong, as the question merely says to find what group the tensor product is isomorphic to, but I believe it must be trivial.

Regardless, doing so "without theorems" is a bit tricky, and I am somewhat unsure what I am meant to do here. My first thought is to try and use some form of bilinear property to say
$\langle a,b\rangle=ab\langle 1,1\rangle =\langle b,a\rangle$, thus $\langle 0,p\rangle=\langle p,0\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and $\langle q,0\rangle =\langle 0,0\rangle $, so as $q$ and $p$ are distinct primes, for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $a'=qa$, and similarly $b'=pb$ for $b\in\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$, so, with those pieces in mind:  for any $a,b$

$\langle a,b\rangle=\langle qa',pb'\rangle=a'b'\langle q,p\rangle=a'b'\langle 0,0\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$, so the entire group is trivial.

Additionally, if instead $p=q$, I believe the tensor product would just return $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or also 0, and I am leaning towards 0 as well in this case, as we may say $p\langle a,b\rangle=\langle 0,b\rangle =\langle a,0\rangle$, thus $\langle a,b\rangle =\langle a,0\rangle +\langle 0,b\rangle =\langle a,0\rangle +\langle a,0\rangle =\langle 2a,0\rangle =2\langle a,0\rangle =\langle a,0\rangle =a\langle 1,0\rangle =\langle 1,0\rangle =\langle 0,1\rangle $ thus any tensor is equal to either basis tensors, meaning the group is trivial.

Am I handling this correctly? Most of my experience tensoring over $\mathbb{Z}$ was with nice theorems that said almost everything goes to 0.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Comment: @ArturoMagidin fixed, forgot I wasn't typing in my own latex document with the shortcuts I set up, thanks

Comment: For the case $p \neq q$, your proof is correct. Moreover, using essentially the same argument, you can show that if $A$ is a ring and $I$ and $J$ are two-sided ideals, then $A/I \otimes_A A/J = A/(I+J)$. In particular, this shows that in the case $p=q$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, there's a mistake in your argument above, because $\langle a,b \rangle$ is not $\langle a,0 \rangle + \langle 0,b \rangle$.

Comment: @Don Thank you, that makes sense! Instead, we may say $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle ab,1\rangle$, so for any two simple tensors $\langle a,b\rangle$, $\langle c,d\rangle$, their sum is $\langle ab,1\rangle+\langle cd,1\rangle=\langle ab+cd,1\rangle$, thus all tensors are simple, and if we define the map $\langle a,b\rangle\mapsto ab$, this turns out to be a group isomorphism into $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, yes?

Comment: @cable Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p\neq q$ we have $q^{-1}\in\Bbb Z_p$. $$a\otimes b=qq^{-1}a\otimes b=q^{-1}a\otimes qb=q^{-1}a\otimes 0=0$$

Comment: Nice! I should have kept things phrased with $\otimes$, this feels much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: And if you are reluctant to use the modular inverse, so can observe that for $x=a\otimes b$ we have both $px=(pa)\otimes b=0\otimes b=0$ as well as $qx=a\otimes(qb)=0$. So the additive order or $x$ is a factor of both $p$ and $q$.... True, soon enough we would be back to Bezout's identity which is equivalent to  the existence of $q^{-1}$ modulo $p$ :-). So +1!